# Meaning of Yii::$app->user->identity->role->role_name;

Tags: yii2, identity, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

In a book called Yii2 for Beginners, which is mainly about the advanced template, I have encountered the following unexplained code, which seems relevant to RBAC:

```
$userHasRoleName = Yii::$app->user->identity->role->role_name;
```

What exactly does this mean? For example, I guess that this:

```
Yii::$app->user
```

refers to this file:

```
vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php
```

Is this correct?

In any case, what does the rest of the code refer to? Specifically:

```
->identity->role->role_name
```

In the above User.php file, I have not been able to find anything like "function identity()", so it can't be that. I have found numerous $identity variables, but I don't know which one the code might be referring to. And there is no $role variable at all.

What is this code referring to:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->role->role_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii described magic methods like __get, __set and so on, to get access for inaccessible properties. Oftenly such methods begins from get or set (in Yii implementation it is). To get access to `->identity`, `\yii\web\User` has method `getIdentity`. This method return identity wich you described in config with `identityClass` property for `user` component. Oftenly `identityClass` is a AR model which implements `IdentityInterface`.

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    ]
]
```

To get access to `->role` for example you must to create a new method

```
namespace common\models;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {

    public function getRole(){
        // if user can have only one role
        return current( \Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser( $this->id ) );
    }
}
```

Btw implementation of `->role->role_name` may be very different.

Comment: Thanks. 

But what makes a property inaccessible? How can I tell whether a property is inaccessible just by looking at it? Which parts of the code I provided are inaccessible? 
Just by looking at this code:
Yii::$app->user->identity->role->role_name;
is there any way to tell that some parts of that are inaccessible? Each of those elements appears to be treated the same way in the syntax, but you're saying that some parts are accessible and others are not, right? Also, you put your getRole method into a "class User". Is that the same "class User" that exists in vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php?

Comment: If you define class attribute as protected or private it become inaccesble outside of class. You can access it inside of class with $this->prop, but you can't get access with $class->prop. Or if you didn't define property at all, virtual attribute, like field from database. OOP means using getters and setters method to access properties. Sometime it's redundantly, but such nature of OOP. Where is no way to determine which part of `Yii::$app->user->identity->role->role_name` is inaccessible. You can only khow it by learning Yii's classes.

Comment: I've just add namespace to User class. If you don't understand what namespaces is, I recomend you to learn it first.

Comment: Thanks. I found "public function getRole" in BaseManager.php. So your example in common\models would be a customization that I would add myself, right? With the help of your explanation, I think I can vaguely understand what the book says about the code, which is: " We are using magic get syntax for the getRole method on the User model, so that is why you see ->role instead of ->getRole(). Once the models are tied together via the relationship, as we put in place in the previous chapter, we can access the properties of the related model, in this case, it’s role_name, which belongs to Role."

Comment: I suggest that BaseManager may be behavior which you need to attach to your User model. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html